# C# VS 2013 how to call programs in DLL

Tags: c#, dll, interop, pinvoke, visual-studio-2013

I have a Delphi created DLL that has functions I need to call from VS 2013 C3 app.
Not exactly sure how or where to start to accomplish this.

Do I have to include the dll as a reference or import it somehow or both?
And how do I call the program?

The dll is MSA.dll and the method I need to call looks like this:

```
GetXML(txtPath.Text, txtCabFile.Text, False);
```

Any 101 basic suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Are you serious???  You reword my question taking out the part stating I had no clue what I was doing and then put this on hold because I did not "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."  You people are insane!!!!!  I said I had no clue how to do it.  What is this site for anyway?  I guess this is a point game to some.

Comment: I will also add I was not looking for code.  I was looking for a place to start and that is what I got in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out something called "P/Invoke."  It allows you to call into "native" (i.e. Delphi, C, etc.) DLLs using simple "extern" function definitions.

Here's a website I use as a resource for P/Invoke calls to the Windows API:
http://www.pinvoke.net/

EDIT: Make sure your target on the .NET side is the same as the one you compiled your Delphi library in.  When in doubt, its probably x86 if you're on a PC.  Thanks to the commenter below who brought this point to my attention.  Don't use AnyCPU.

EDIT 2: The extern declaration you would use:

```
[DllImport("MSA.dll", CharSet = Ansi)]
public extern string GetXML(string firstParam, string secondParam, bool thirdParam);
```

You can name the parameters whatever you want.  I didn't know what to call them so I just gave them names.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that if your Delphi DLL is 32bit, you must compile your C# app to target "x86" instead of "AnyCPU" or the calls will fail.

Comment: I added this to my answer, thanks :)

Comment: Added a P/Invoke declaration for clarity and usefulness